# R: how can I replace specific entries of a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, replace

Let

`m <- 3*matrix(1:12, 3, 4)`

using the which() function I then can access all entries that are above a given threshold like so

`which(m > 25)`
which returns a list of integer entry indices, or

`which(m > 25, arr.ind = TRUE)` returning more matrix-like indices.

However I cannot use something like `m[which(m > 25)]` in order to change those values (say to 100). I would greatly appreciate any pointers :)

Comment: You can do `m[which(m > 25)] <- 100` or even `m[m > 25] <- 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
m[m>25] <- 100
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3   12   21  100
[2,]    6   15   24  100
[3,]    9   18  100  100
```